# Dialogflow is automatically signing me out, whenever I am trying to use the "Try it now" feature

Tags: dialogflow-es

Whenever I am trying to test my intents in the Dialogflow "Try it now" tab, Dialogflow automatically logs out. Have anyone faced the same issue ? How to resolve it ?

n.b. I am using webhook for some intents

Comment: Could you provide more details about your agent ? Also, have you tried opening it in another browser? Did it always happen with you?

Comment: My agent provides answer for banking related queries. I tried opening it on another browser ,It happens there too. Some of my intents uses webhook in fulfillment.

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue. Could you edit your question with the configuration of you agent and your code since you use webhook fulfillment?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem on my other chatbot that doesn't have any webhook fulfillment

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I managed to solve it by deleting the agent and recreating and import it to the existing google cloud project.

but I still have the same problem whenever I import a prebuilt agent, my current google cloud project won't show in the google cloud project list (i think this is because only one agent allowed per project), and if tried the "try it now" on the prebuilt agent it will redirect me to log in.